# Detecting BTC transaction hash data: help

Tags: transactions, hash, sending

please I need some help in reading the hash data correctly.
Given below transaction of total value btc 1.55821903
https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/8bbae353ce95fb0a6cbff44b8dd1c3cdd7d6419e0c63ee73f59db7cc0c110dc1

Only btc 0.00621581 were effectively received by B (recipient)?

The amount come back to A (btc 1.55200322) was not sent to B at all?

Therefore, can A say "I paid B with btc amount 1.55821903" in any ways?

Many thanks to the community

Answer (score 1):

> can A say "I paid B with btc amount 1.55821903" in any ways?

No.

A used a 1.55824169 BTC "coin" but sent themselves change in the form of a 1.55200322 BTC "coin". B only ever received a 0.00621581 BTC "coin" and nothing else. B never had any control over the amount of change.

At no time did B have any control over the 1.55824169 BTC "coin".

At no time was there ever any  1.55821903 BTC "coin". That amount is just the sum of the two "coins" created in this transaction.

The difference between 1.55824169 BTC and 1.55821903 BTC is the fee amount that a miner will *include* in the coinbase "coin" that they create. The face value of the coinbase "coin" will be a larger amount because it typically includes other fees from other transactions in the same block and a mining reward for the block of transactions.